# Query analyzer tool, specifically for Derby SQL

Tags: sql, derby

I've seen a little info for [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/) as a query analyzer for Derby. Are there any other ones out there? I'm looking open source ideally, or something that has a cheap license so I can implement.

I'm also considering building my own. I mostly need a GUI for simple report building. But I'm sure that's a big undertaking.

Does anyone know of a tool, or can they recommend some reading for a good understanding of what a tool might need?

My current approach involves query the SYS tables for the schema's then representing them graphically in JTables. Each table is on a tab and you can add tables to a view, then create a report. It's a bit clunky.

I'll delete if this question is way too broad.